# Where does ColdFusion store .HBXML files?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion

Where does ColdFusion store .HBXML files when the `ormsettings.savemapping = false;`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not saved if the setting is false. If true, they're dropped right next to the corresponding entity cfc.